# Number of DAX code lines in entire Power BI report

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to monitor the total number of DAX lines of all DAX measures of the Power BI report? Or alternatively, the total string length of all DAX measures in the Power BI report?

I want to get a glimpse of the DAX code complexity. Similarly, View Metrix in Dax Studio shows basic stats on the physical part of the model but not on the DAX part. The total length of a DAX code of all measures how complex the report is.

One of the key characteristics of the code is its readability which is, to a great extent, achieved by brevity.

[image]

Comment: Is there a logical reason for Power BI to store such information somewhere? To count the number of DAX measure lines, and then next? For what reason he will do that ?

Comment: Can you share more about what you're trying to accomplish? If it has to do with speed, I wouldn't think the number of characters in the measures would correlate very well.

Answer (score 2):

You can run queries against the [Dynamic Management Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions) or DMVs in Dax Studio, eg:

```
select * from $System.TMSCHEMA_MEASURES
```